# 2D Dynamic array failure to delete

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

So this is certain to be a ridiculous querstion but, I've searched and searched with no avail.  This said, there's probably one of Murphy's laws which states that once you've posted a question, someone will direct you to an identical post 5 min later...

Anyway, I create a 2D array using the following function:

```
double** matrixCreate(int rows, int cols, double initialValue)
{
    double** temp; temp=new double*[rows];
    for(int j=0;j<rows;j++) {temp[j]=new double [cols];}

    //Set  initial  values   
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)  
    {  
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            temp[i][j]=initialValue;
        }
    }

    return  temp;
}
```

I then do some stuff with the matrix, and then delete via the following function:

```
void  matrixDestroy(double** &temp,int rows)
{
    for(int j=0;j<rows;j++) 
    {
        delete[] temp[j];
    }

    delete[] temp;
}
```

Unfortunately, despite my careful attempt at management, Visual Leak Detector says I did something wrong.  strangely enough, I have similar creation and deletion functions for one dimensional arrays which are fine.

Furthermore, if, after calling matrixDestroy, I try to reuse the same variable name of the (supposedly) deleted matrix (declaring it as a different type) I get an error.  Not sure if this is a symptom or a limitation.  Does anyone know if you should be able to do this?

Any help would be welcome.  Thanks, hope it's something obvious.

I should mention that yes, I did make sure that the number of rows given is correct.  For those interested in what the "stuff" I do with the matrix, it's part of a multidimension Nelder Mead minimization engine.

===============================UPDATE=======================
Alright. I found it.  Kind of embarrassing really.  I tried to write a double* to one of the "rows" without first freeing its memory.  Oops!

Fixed now though.  Thanks for all the help!  Turns out the matrixDestroy function is all fine.  I should have known that it would have been something a little more buried.

Comment: Can you show us how you call your functions ?

Comment: Functions are called as follows: double** mat=matrixCreate(5,5,(double) 0);  and matrixDestroy(mat,5);

Comment: Just don't use raw arrays use stl instead.std::vector< std::vector<double> > is what you need.

Comment: hmmm.. this seems to compile : [Tested here with g++ 4.8.1](http://ideone.com/yZiwUG). What compiler did you use ?

Comment: Haha, I love vectors!  A while back I did some speed tests and they were about three time slower than using dynamic arrays.  Since this is being used in a minimization engine, speed is important.

Comment: Oh it compiles alright, but it leaks memory - not sure why.  Something about the cleanup isn't cleaning up everything...  It's not a lot of memory either but if your running it several hundred thousand times it adds up!